# Git not prompting for password when in chroot

Tags: git, passwords, prompt, strace, chroot

I'm creating my own custom chroot environment and was trying to add git functionality to it. It is functioning for the most parts but I cannot seem to find how to make the git prompt for password. I can embed it into a single line when I try operations like clone push pull but I would prefer the prompt to actually show... :) I've tried to strace the git to see if I've missed some thing which might git be using but nothing is reported that might be significant. I'm quite a nub with strace so I might be missing something, in any case if some one had this case before I would appreciate the help.